# Why does Mr. Brooks call Atwood?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, mr-brooks

Recently I've watched the movie named [Mr.Brooks](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780571/). It was a wonderful movie with lots of twists and it certainly has its fair share of suspense and violence.

But I don't understand, **Why does Mr. Brooks call Atwood after killing Mr. Smith?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because he wants to know why she became a police officer given that she is very rich, could have gone into her father's business, or just lived the high life.

Comment: .@Evan,Thanks Evan.Even if you think so,What is the necessary to use Mr.Smith's name in that conversation?

Comment: He never said who he was. Atwood asked if he was "Mr Baffort" but he never really acknowledged that. The closest he got was saying "I have a little cold" when she said "It doesn't sound like you." It was all cat and mouse between them, getting what they wanted to know.